# PDF - How to embed GeoSpatial data programmatically?

Tags: pdf

How can I programmatically embed metadata into a PDF document, .e.g georeferences?

Any and all advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what language?  Existing PDFs, or ones you're creating with some library?  We need a lot more information than that to be useful.

Comment: If you can afford a commercial option, you could use Amyuni PDF Converter (http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfconverter/features.html) The API for geo-registration is not online yet but it will be given to you if you contact the support team. (Disclaimer: I work in Amyuni Technologies).